# Crystal Report Data field type different with dataset data type

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, types, crystal-reports, dataset

I have a crystal report that bound to a dataset, the dataset is filled using stored proc. Some of my numeric columns mysterisly become string in crystal report. I have checked the columns in the dataset, and they are all system.decimal.

Because I have to do calculations and grouping in the report, I have formulas to convert all thoes string to double. It works, but I have already a hung rows of formulas and it will grow longer.

I don't know what's the problem, please help if you suspect anything could cause this.

Thank you.

Comment: How are the columns cast in the stored procedure?

Comment: the stored proc is a little crazy, most of those columns look like select isnull(sum(decEarnedhrs), 0) from... join join.. where... as columnname

Comment: should I cast them into decimal in the stored proc?

Comment: Couldn't hurt; at least it would rule out the stored procedure

Comment: The funny thing is I only cast one column into decimal, and all the other columns show up as number in crystal report as well. Those columns are pretty independent from each other.

Comment: Crystal Reports can be a strange creature; I can't tell you how many times I've seen something weird, found a workaround, and just shrugged my shoulders :)  Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your data types are cast as `decimal` in your stored procedure.  I've seen Crystal Reports come up with its own datatypes if it can't figure it out own its own.